# Is it possible to display empty string instead of 0 in DataGridView int columns?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataTable filled with information about audio tracks. DataTableColumn that stores the track number is of a UInt32 type so when I display the DataTable in DataGridView, I'm able to sort data by that column. For tracks when there is no track number I've got 0 in DataTable.

```
data.Tables["active"].Columns["Track"].DataType = Type.GetType("System.UInt32");
```

Is it possible to display every 0 in that column in DataGridView as an empty string (nothing)? But still have it stored as UInt32 0 in DataTable to be able to sort the tracks?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure, you can use the `CellFormatting` event:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName == "Track")
    {
        uint value = (uint)e.Value;
        if (value == 0)
        {
            e.Value = string.Empty;
            e.FormattingApplied = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If someone else is interested I modified the code a little bit so it's not dependent on the column name:
`if (dataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].ValueType == Type.GetType("System.UInt32"))`
{ // Thomas's code }

Comment: @JoudicekJouda, you should use `typeof(UInt32)` rather than `Type.GetType("System.UInt32")`...

Comment: @Thomas Levesque:  Thread necromancy.    It should be possible to do this with just a data template, right?  If so, do you know how to do it.

Comment: @SezMe, this is WinForms, not WPF... there are no templates ;)

Answer (score 0):

just a small suggestion ... add another column with "System.String" and make it's value equal to Track column (hide track column) and then you can replace 0 with empty string in the new visible column

Answer (score 0):

An alternate `CellFormatting` function that displays an empty cell without changing the actual cell value:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName == "Track")
{
    if (e.Value == 0)
    {
        e.CellStyle.Format = ";;;";
    }
}
```